# if a set B has a least upper bound of an on an ordered relation <(a) then will it have least upper bound on an ordered relation <(b)

Tags: relations

given a set B ordered by a relation <(a) has a least upper bound property, does B have an least upper bound property if it is ordered by another ordered relation <(b).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not necessarily.
Let $B=\mathbb R$ and $<_a$ the standard order (which has the least upper bound property). Let $<_b$ be defined by
$$x<_by\iff x<y\lor (x\notin\mathbb Q\land y\in\mathbb Q).$$
Then $\{\,x\in\mathbb Q\mid x^2<2\,\}$ has $42$ as upper bound, but no least upper bound. Also, the set $\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q$ has $-666$ as upper bound, but no least upper bound.